# Angular build not responsive on mobile phone

Tags: html, css, json, angular, npm

I have a problem with my angular build.
I deployed me website here: https://stately-brioche-8f94ce.netlify.app/

As you see, it looks good and also if you open up the devtools.

But as soon as I open it on my phone, it looks disgusting!

Any ideas?

I already checked my angular.json file -> everything looks fine.

Comment: this isn't a *specific* debugging problem, not sure why you're referring to angular.json since styles are controlled by css/scss etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I like your website, it looks fun!
It sounds like you need to look into making it dynamic, meaning the website will adjust its content to the different screen sizes. Here is a [blog post](https://www.devintent.com/blog/2022-10-04-react-to-screen-size-changes-in-angular) using @angular/cdk package to help make dynamic components.